# scala api document in REPL

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm new at Scala programming and prefer to code in terminal other than eclipse thought it is pretty nice. One thing I couldn't find any information yet is how to retrieve api documents on Scala REPL (that is "scala" or "sbt" command) like python or ipython response on help() or putting "?" at the end of api respectively. Even Scala seems not have any command like "pydoc" for Python or "man" for C language.

Is it true that only way to find api document is by browsing document with web form or am I missing?

Comment: Check out IntelliJ Idea (Community Edition). It is much faster than Eclipse, runs smoothly. You also have access to Scala Console from within the IDE. If you import an SBT project, it can automatically download available sources & documentation, and you just `CTRL+Q` to see the docs, or `CTRL+B` to see the impl.

Comment: @ponythewhite Thanks, but as I mentioned above, ubiquitous terminals and shells are always the best in my taste. And it is true that the Eclipse is heaviness and I don't like it, but we have Eclipse for Scala which show fare performance and also pretty nice to have such "worksheet" on it.

Anyway, better for others to have various choices. I'll try just for experiencing new environment. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it true that only way to find api document is by browsing document with web form or am I missing?

It sort of is true at this point.

I wrote an sbt plugin [sbt-man](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-man) but its ability is limited.

```
> man Traversable /:
[man] scala.collection.Traversable
[man] def /:[B](z: B)(op: (B ⇒ A ⇒ B)): B
[man] Applies a binary operator to a start value and all elements of this
collection, going left to right. Note: /: is alternate syntax for foldLeft;
z /: xs is the same as xs foldLeft z. Note: will not terminate for infinite-
sized collections. Note: might return different results for different runs,
unless the underlying collection type is ordered. or the operator is
associative and commutative.
```

For easier downloading I also wrote [doctrine](https://github.com/eed3si9n/doctrine).

```
$ doctrine "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % "2.11.2" -o ~/doc
[info] unzippped documents to /Users/foo/doc/scala-library-2.11.2-javadoc
```

Comment: Nice, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Nice work, too bad scalex is stuck at scala 2.9.2. While still useful, it might be confusing when hitting on an API that changed since then.